# c#, passing any array to C++ dll with a single function

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers, interop

For now I'm using below definition in the C# side

```
[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWrite(IntPtr handle,float[] obj);
```

to send a float array to C space in a c++ dll as in below definition

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void bufferWrite(OpenClBuffer * handle, void * ptr)
{
        ...
}
```

and it works(or seems like working). Now I need to support double, long and byte arrays too. Also I dont want to rewrite additional functions in c++ dll because it is already using a void pointer and size of buffer is handled by some other parameters inside.

**Is it legal to use "ref object obj" instead of "float[] obj" or "long [] obj" in the C# space for all platforms(32 bit, 64 bit, xp,7,8.1,10) as in below**

```
[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWrite(IntPtr handle,ref object obj);
```

or do I need to add extra functions to c++ such as

```
[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWriteFloat(...);

[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWriteInt(...);

[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWriteLong(...);
```

and make them call same old function with a casting to (void *)? Maybe just overloading the function in C# is enough and workds 100% of time?

```
[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWrit(..., float[] obj);

[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWrite(..., long[] obj);

[DllImport("CL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr bufferWrite(..., double[] obj);
```

I'm assuming a void pointer is always same size as an array pointer when C#-C++ interop is used.

Comment: Last snippet is fine, assuming that this function somehow magically knows the size of the array elements and the length of the array.  Those kind of important details don't tend to teleport that well but there's nothing in this question that says it definitely can't work.

Comment: Yes it knows size by using the handle. I just want to wrap opencl c++ for my C# projects. Im using the last snipped then. Thank you.